# First input link main timebase (1/12800) do not match the corresponding second input link xfade timebase (1/90000)

Tags: ffmpeg

I  am getting the error `First input link main timebase (1/12800) do not match the corresponding second input link xfade timebase (1/90000)` when I run the following ffmpeg cmd:

```
ffmpeg -y -progress .progressinfo.dat 
 -i "E:/tmp/_MERGED.Test0.mp4" -i "E:/tmp/f3.ts" 
 -filter_complex "
 [0][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=1.645,format=yuv420p ; 
 [0:a][1:a]acrossfade=d=1" 
 -movflags +faststart  "E:/_MERGED.Test.mp4"
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of help from Rotem (thank you again Rotem), and different attempts and lots of resulting problems, I think I've found my solution - and it was to bail out of trying to do it in one hit and break it up into 3 - (a) video merge + (b) audio merge + (c) blend video and audio together.

To do this I found a very helpful webpage  https://romander.github.io/ffmpeg-script-generator/, that gave me the commands I needed (use the "*Generate audio and video scripts separately? (separate scripts more effective)*" checkbox).

(Note, I also added `-crf 0` to the ffmpeg video merge (a) and final merge (c) commands).

Answer (score 1):

You may correct the timebase using [`settb` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-settb_002c-asettb).

In case there is an issue with the audio, use `asettb` filter.

In the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-Examples-80) example, the `settb` is followed by `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS`, for fixing the timestamps.

---

Command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -progress .progressinfo.dat 
       -i "E:/tmp/_MERGED.Test0.mp4" 
       -i "E:/tmp/f3.ts" 
       -filter_complex "[0:v]settb=AVTB,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];
                        [1:v]settb=AVTB,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];
                        [v0][v1]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=1.645,format=yuv420p;
                        [0:a]asettb=AVTB,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];
                        [1:a]asettb=AVTB,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];
                        [a0][a1]acrossfade=d=1" 
        -movflags +faststart 
        "E:\tmp\out_MERGED.Test.mp4"
```

Comment: Thanks Rotem, that worked in terms of "it ran" and produced a result, but now I am finding the sound quality is fuzzy after a few "merges" (i.e. f1.ts merged with f2.ts = output1.mp4, then output1.mp4 merged with f3.ts = output2.mp4, etc).

Comment: I don't have much experience with audio. Try not to correct the audio timebase.

Comment: Every merge, there is some quality loss. It is recommended to merge all the files in one command. If you can't, use losless audio and video codecs for the intermediate results. Re-encode the final result.

Comment: I have actually tried doing it in one command (see https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/r2L3evwg/) but after about an hour of maxed CPU - I get an error "Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory" "Error while processing the decoded data for stream #12:0" (see https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/2sqvpmx7/2/). It seems that running in one go would be faster - and indeed the other option was incredibly slow when trying more than a few files.

Comment: You can try converting all the files to uncompressed AVI, with pcm_s16le audio codec and rawvideo video codec. Merge all the files. Encode the result to MP4 with H.264 and AAC codec.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a go (any suggestion what command I do to do that against each source f#.mp4 file?) (my current set of prep commands are seen here : https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/q0zkcur2/4/)

Comment: Example for converting TS to uncompressed AVI: `ffmpeg -y -i E:/tmp/f3.ts -vf settb=AVTB,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS -af asettb=AVTB,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS -vcodec rawvideo -acodec pcm_s16le -pix_fmt bgr24 E:/tmp/f3.avi` (I don't know if you need the `-vf settb=AVTB,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS` and `-af asettb=AVTB,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS` it depends on input).

Comment: Apply the xfade and acrossfade on uncompressed AVI (add `-vcodec rawvideo -acodec pcm_s16le -pix_fmt bgr24 tmp_file_name.avi`). Convert the final result to MP4. Example: `ffmpeg -y -i E:/tmp/f3.avi -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -pix_fmt yuv420p E:/tmp/f3.mp4`.

Comment: Thanks Rotem, but I'm not having much luck with this; I've tried your .AVI option, but found that the audio was crackly/glitchy, so I removed the settb & settps options as a test and it did improve things, but when trying the full set of videos I ran out of disk space (500GB+). I've tried it with a smaller set and it does work - but after about 15 videos I think I'm seeing the video and audio slightly out of sync.

Comment: Well... may answer addresses the error message, I was not intended to solve any other problem. Why did you have the  timebase issue anyway? It looks like all your input files are TS files (probably with the same timebase). I don't know why the video and audio are getting out of sync. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63553906/merging-multiple-video-files-with-ffmpeg-and-xfade-filter) it should have worked in a single command without corrections. But then you are getting out of memory...